# Polymer - How to bind event to a group of button at once

Tags: polymer

```
<core-menu selected="0">
    <core-item class="menu-link" icon="info" label="About us"></core-item>
    <core-item class="menu-link" icon="image:portrait" label="Professor"></core-item>
    <core-item class="menu-link" icon="social:group" label="Members"></core-item>
</core-menu>
```

I got a core-menu contains a group of core-item, and I want to bind click event to them with the code below

```
var menulink = document.querySelector('.menu-link');
menulink.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(this.label);            
});
```

But it only works to the first core-item, how to resolve this?

Also tried with the

```
var menulink = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-link');
menulink.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(this.label);            
});
```

But i got Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` should work. Can you post a jsbin that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Yes, it works, but when I add event like menulink.addEventListener, I got Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. BTW, how do I import html in jsbin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it only works to the first core-item, how to resolve this?

That's because, as Peter Burns commented, `querySelector` only returns the first matching element and ignores the others.

> Also tried with [`querySelectorAll`] but i got Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

This is because `querySelectorAll` returns an array of matching elements, and `addEventListener` isn't a method attached to the array object - it's instead attached to each individual element contained within the array. To overcome this we need to loop through each returned element and assign the event listener to each:

```
var menulinks = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-link');

for (var i = 0; i < menulinks.length; i++)
    menulinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log(this.label);            
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, problem resolved. Is it the common way to handle the problem?